# Rename Excel Sheet Name in SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

SQL 2008 / VS 2008

I am exporting Excel Sheet to SQL Database. This package will be called from C# Application.

As the Sheet Name varies from Excel Sheet to Excel Sheet, Package fails. I have written a query inside the package as follows ..

select colum1,column2 from 'Sheet1$'

This Query exports data to SQL Database.

If i am able to rename the First Sheet Tab of the Excel Sheet as Sheet1, I will not be having any problem on Exporting to SQL DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to use a Script Task to [rename the sheet](http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.com/2010/04/rename-excel-sheet-net.html). Alternatively, you could write a Script Component to output the data directly from C# without altering the workbook or using SQL.

Comment: Okay, i agree with you that we have to write C# code in the Script Task to rename the Sheet. can i have a sample code to do this process ?

Comment: Did you click on the link in my reply? Or just Google "C# rename Excel worksheet".